# What's the value of $k$ given $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$ without using L'Hospital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Just recently, I was asked to solve this question in my exam. It is the following question.

Given
$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{\sin\left(\pi (\cos(x))^2\right)}{x^2}, & \text{ if } x \not= 0 \\
  k, & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{array}
\right.$

is continuous at $x = 0$. Find the value of $k$.

Since, we know that this function is continuous at $x = 0$. We can imply that,
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin \left(\pi (\cos(h))^2\right)}{h^2}=k$$

I computed the limit using L'Hospital rule and it was $\pi$, but I was wondering how to compute it without the use of L'Hospital rule.

Comment: well, you can try Taylor's expansion of the numerator.

Comment: @OnoL I forgot to mention, i can't use it since my teacher told me to solve it using what was covered in syllabus. And Apparently, there are no Taylor expansions and L'hospital rule in my syllabus :(

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the function is continuous at $x=0$ then can't you set the previous equation to 0 and solve from there?

Comment: @GilKeidar He needs to find $k$ so that it is continuous. It is when $k=\pi$.

Comment: @OnoL For analytic functions, L'H is a trivial consequence of the existence of the Taylor series. I would be very hesitant to use Taylor series if L'H is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ we get
$$\;\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin (\pi (\cos(h))^2)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin (\pi- \pi (\cos(h))^2)}{h^2}\\
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin (\pi-\pi (\cos(h))^2)}{\pi- \pi (\cos(h))^2}\cdot \pi \cdot\frac{1- \cos(h)^2}{h^2}=\pi\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin (\pi-\pi (\cos(h))^2)}{\pi- \pi (\cos(h))^2}\cdot\frac{\sin(h)^2}{h^2}$$

Now both limits are 1 by the fundamental trig limit.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Taylor expansions
$$
\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(\cos(h)\right)^2\right)}{h^2}=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(1-h^2/2+o\left(h^2\right)\right)^2\right)}{h^2}=\frac{\sin\left(\pi-\pi h^2 +o\left(h^2\right)\right)}{h^2}\underset{(0)}{\sim}\frac{\sin\left(\pi h^2\right)}{h^2}
$$
Hence

> $$
> \frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(\cos(h)\right)^2\right)}{h^2}\underset{(0)}{\sim}\frac{\pi h^2}{h^2}=\pi$$

Comment: Thanks @Atmos, but i can't use Taylor expansion but, it's a neat answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {sin(\pi(cosx)^2)}{x^2}=\frac {sin(\pi-\pi(cosx)^2)}{x^2}=\frac {sin(\pi(sinx)^2)}{x^2}=\frac {sin(\pi(sinx)^2)}{\pi(sinx)^2}\frac{\pi(sinx)^2}{x^2}$ Now as $x\rightarrow 0$ the limit is $\pi$.So $ k= \pi.$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\sin(π(1-\sin^2h))}{h^2} = $

$\dfrac{-\cos(π)\sin(π\sin^2h)}{h^2}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(π\sin^2h)}{π\sin^2h} \dfrac{π\sin^2h}{h^2}.$

Limit:

1)$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin(π\sin^2h)}{π\sin^2h}=1;$

2)$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{π\sin^2h}{h^2}=π$